# Need to get all the values of all the child component instances and use it in parents method: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, setstate, react-table

I have this scenario where I have a table(react-table), where I am applying column level filtering. I have extracted this as a separate component(DropdDown Component) and this can be attached to any column . I am maintaining  a method inside parent component which picks up the union of all the values i.e., selected values of all the dropdowns and then apply server side filtering.

Now the challenge here is , How can i get this consolidated values inside the parent component method?

This DropDown component has list of unique values with respect to that column, there is an Apply button , which applies the server side filtering. Now if I jump onto another column, I need to get the previously checked values and also the current values.

Inside handleSetData() filtering logic is written, I need to get the data from DropDown Component. Everytime I click on Apply on a column filter, I need to get the previously checked values as well.

Can someone help me with this:

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-glitter-np8iw

### App Component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "./styles.css";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import DropDownComponent from "./DropDown";
interface IState {
  data: {}[];
  columns: {}[];
}

interface IProps {}

export default class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { firstName: "aaaaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 },
        { firstName: "aabFaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 },
        { firstName: "adaAAaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 1785 },
        { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 175 },
        { firstName: "adaSaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 165 },
        { firstName: "aaaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 157 },
        { firstName: "aaaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 153 },
        { firstName: "aaaaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 }
      ],
      columns: []
    };
  }

  handleSetState = (columns: any) => {
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  handleSetData = (value: any) => {
    console.log(value); // Here filtering logic is written, I need to get the data from DropDown Component. Everytime I click on Apply on a column filter, I need to get the previously checked values as well
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let columns = [
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", marginLeft: "10px" }}>
              <DropDownComponent
                data={this.state.data}
                handleSetData={this.handleSetData}
                param="firstName"
              />
            </div>
            <span>First Name</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "firstName",
        sortable: false,
        show: true,
        displayValue: " First Name"
      },
      {
        Header: () => (
          <div>
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", marginLeft: "10px" }}>
              <DropDownComponent
                data={this.state.data}
                handleSetData={this.handleSetData}
                param="status"
              />
            </div>
            <span>Status</span>
          </div>
        ),
        accessor: "status",
        sortable: false,
        show: true,
        displayValue: " Status "
      },
      {
        Header: "Visits",
        accessor: "visits",
        sortable: false,
        show: true,
        displayValue: " Visits "
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  }

  render() {
    const { data, columns } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### DropDown Component

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Checkbox, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
interface IProps {
  data: {}[];
  handleSetData(arr: any): void;
  param: string;
}
interface IState {
  showList: boolean;
  optionsArr: {}[];
  originalState: {}[];
}

export default class DropDownComponent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showList: false,
      optionsArr: [],
      originalState: []
    };
  }

  toggleList = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ showList: !prevState.showList }));
  };

  handleItemClick = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, data: any) => {
    const index = this.state.optionsArr.findIndex(
      (item: any) => item.text === data.name
    );
    const optionsArr = this.state.optionsArr.map((prevState: any, i: any) =>
      i === index
        ? {
            key: prevState.key,
            text: prevState.text,
            checked: !prevState.checked
          }
        : prevState
    );
    this.setState({ optionsArr });
  };

  submitSelection = () => {
    console.log(this.state.optionsArr.filter((item: any) => item.checked)); // This gives me selecte ones
    let checkedValues: any = this.state.optionsArr.filter(
      (item: any) => item.checked
    );
    this.setState({ originalState: this.state.optionsArr }, () =>
      this.props.handleSetData(checkedValues)
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.data) {
      let arr = this.props.data;
      let uniqueValues = Array.from(
        new Set(arr.map((arr: any) => arr[this.props.param]))
      );
      var optionsArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++) {
        var options: any = {};
        options["key"] = uniqueValues[i];
        options["text"] = uniqueValues[i];
        options["checked"] = false;
        optionsArr.push(options);
      }
      this.setState({ optionsArr: optionsArr, originalState: optionsArr });
    }
  }

  clearSelection = (event: any) => {
    // Push it to previous state, before cancel was clicked
    this.setState({ showList: false, optionsArr: this.state.originalState });
  };

  render() {
    let { showList } = this.state;
    let visibleFlag: string;
    if (showList === true) visibleFlag = "visible";
    else visibleFlag = "";
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
          <div
            className={
              "ui scrolling dropdown column-settings customized " +
              visibleFlag +
              " " +
              this.props.menuDirection
            }
          >
            <Icon className="filter" onClick={this.toggleList} />
              {this.state.optionsArr.length > 0 ? (
                <>
                  <div className="menu-item-holder">
                    {this.state.optionsArr.map((item: any, i: number) => (
                      <div className="menu-item" key={i}>
                        <Checkbox
                          name={item.text}
                          onChange={this.handleItemClick}
                          checked={item.checked}
                          label={item.text}
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                  <div className="menu-btn-holder">
                    <Button size="small" onClick={this.submitSelection}>
                      Apply
                    </Button>
                    <Button size="small" onClick={this.clearSelection}>
                      Cancel
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your DropDown component. I make it receive a list of items to generate the checkboxes. Instead of sending the whole data object to the DropDown component, I think it makes more sense send a ready list to them, the Main component should generate the right data structure (I haven't done that, you have to create those functions). In the component, I create three states to manage the component.

Obs: I removed typescript to make faster for me.
[condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-compoent-stackoverflow-kozgu)

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I am doing this way here is there are other filters as well,  such column level search filter, global search filter where this filtering must happen . So I thought of having this data object being sent to all these filter components and let them handle the data and send the result to the parent. It would be really great if you can edit my sandbox and bring in the functionality ! Just need the data of these individual column filters components inside App component handleSetData  method so that filtering will happen based on values selected across the columns. Thanks again

Comment: Usually, the best option is to have your Dumb components the most simple is possible and prepare all the data structure in your containers. I am already sending the keys, o can check on index.js `handleSetData` function. If you need the whole objects, just create another function inside the DropDown component to create a map based on the selected ids.